# p is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using OpenXML and C# to build an application. I think this is a common error more related to C# than to other stuff.

I want to access `p` outside of the scope of the `foreach` loop, so I assign it as a global variable, but I get this error:

> p is a variable but is used like a type

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
foreach (p in myIEnumerable){
    /* Do something with p */
}
```

Comment: Rename Paragraph p = new Paragraph(); it should work

Comment: How are you going to "use it outside the foreach" when its a loop - `p` after the loop will contain the very last item in the list

Comment: p is only meaningful inside the foreach scope. It is useless outside the loop, unless you want to use only the last item of the list you are looping through.

Comment: the last found is the one i want to treat

Comment: `p` is a variable name. In a perfect world, one letter variable names would be punishable by restricting people from working as a programmer.

Comment: Zohar you know what is test purposes? or you build perfect pictures in your first time ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled you've never done `for(var i =0;i<....)` I take it.

Comment: Yeah, ok, with some exceptions like loop counters and stuff like that, but usually, even for my labmda expressions I use a names that are a little more meaningful then a single letter.

Comment: well, seems like you will be restricted to be a programmer :D

Comment: @ZoharPeled so, what you;re saying is you're just as guilty and should be restricted from working as a programmer. As should I and 100% of other programmers. Hint: Dont make sweeping generalizations!

Comment: My point is that you should never code atrocities like Paragraph p = new Paragraph().

Comment: dunno why there are some hatters, we are all learning all the time even when it is the most obvious thing in the world

Comment: @FilipeCosta What if zohar is not a hater and there is really something to learn here. :)

Comment: Harsh as i said, i know about that already, i am doing some tests, i don't do the perfect code writing when i do simple test purposes that i will change, it doens't make sense

Comment: Zohar i know about that, but the question had nothing to do with the variable name, as i said this is a simple test and it doesn't make sense to build wonderful code when i need to rewrite it soon, so simple as that

Comment: @FilipeCosta I was just making a simple observation. I have no way of knowing what you know and what you don't know. My comment have nothing to do with you as a person, just with this line of code. I'm sorry if you got the wrong impression but I have reviewed code written by members of my team that had variable names like this, and had them rewrite it. I couldn't possibly know your background and purpose of your code.

Comment: don't worry, just next time don't go so hard on someone when you don't know what is going on :), i am not a pro programmer, but i know when i need to speed up code to do tests for ME or when i need to do someone for people to read, thank you anyways for helping :)

Answer (score 8):

The reason you get the error

> p is a variable but is used like a type

Is because the syntax of a `foreach` loop is

```
for([type] [variable] in [enumerable])
```

You've used the variable `p` in place of the expected Type (note you can substitute the type for the keyword `var`)

Answer (score 1):

The error is a syntax error.  You should have

```
foreach (var p in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants...
```

Then as the others pointed out, you will have a problem with declaring a new variable named `p` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for foreach is

```
foreach(var p in myList){//myList is some collection

}
```

This is why you are getting the error. First word inside the brackets after foreach keyword should be a type(Class name or any other type) or var keyword.

So, in your case, you should do below

```
Paragraph p = null;
foreach(var p1 in myList){
   p = p1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are appending values into `P` instead append it into a List

```
List<Paragraph> pList = new List<Paragraph>();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
foreach (p in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Equals("The contents of this...")))
{
    pList.Append(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })); 
    pList.ElementsAfter();
 }
```

I prefer this:

```
var Par = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Equals("The contents of this..."));
foreach (p in Par)
{
    pList.Append(new Run(new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })); 
    pList.ElementsAfter();
 }
```

Comment: This will still give you a syntax error because you are missing the type or var keyword

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
foreach (Paragraph p in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Equals("")))
{
    /*body*/
}
```

If you need the last `p` after the foreach, you can get it by calling:

```
Paragraph p = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Equals(""))).Last();
```

And to avoid dupplicate code:

```
IEnumerable i = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Equals("")));
foreach(Paragraph p in i)
/*body*/
Paragraph p = i.Last();
```